# How to raise textInput over keyboard? (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, layout, keyboard

I am trying to make it so that when a textInput is in focus, it is raised over the keyBoard. I didn't figure out how to make the KeyboardAvoidingView play well with my current layout but if someone finds a way to make it work let me know. This is what I have for now:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  ImageBackground,
  Keyboard,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from "react-native";

import { COLORS } from "../../assets/Colors/Colors";

import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton";
import CustomInput from "../../components/CustomInput";
import SocialSignInButtons from "../../components/SocialSignInButtons";

const SignUpScreen = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);
  const [isOnFocus, setIsOnFocus] = useState(0);
  const [top1, setTop1] = useState(0);
  const [top2, setTop2] = useState(0);

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const window = useWindowDimensions();
  const textInput1 = useRef();
  const textInput2 = useRef();
  const textInputs = [textInput1, textInput2];
  const setTops = [setTop1, setTop2];

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      textInputs[0].current?.focus();
    }, 0);
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      (e) => {
        setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
      }
    );

    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener();

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const onRegisterPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignUp2");
  };

  const onSignInPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignIn");
  };

  const onTermsOfUsePressed = () => {
    console.warn("Terms of Use");
  };
  const onPrivacyPolicyPressed = () => {
    console.warn("Privacy Policy");
  };

  const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    eval(`set${type}`)(e);
  };

  const dimensions = (layout, i) => {
    textInputs[i].current?.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      console.log("Component width is: " + width);
      console.log("Component height is: " + height);
      console.log("X offset to frame: " + x);
      console.log("Y offset to frame: " + y);
      console.log("X offset to page: " + pageX);
      console.log("Y offset to page: " + pageY);
      setTops[i](pageY);
    });
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      //ref={textInputs[0]}
      resizeMode="stretch"
      source={require("../../assets/AppCustomBackgroundsFrench/SignUpFR.png")}
      style={styles.imageBackground}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.title, { top: window.height * 0.34 }]}>
        S'inscrire
      </Text>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
          top: window.height * 0.37,
        }}
      >
        <CustomInput
          ref={textInputs[0]}
          onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "Username")}
          placeholder="Username"
          style={
            isOnFocus == 1
              ? {
                  position: "absolute",
                  width: "100%",
                  bottom: keyboardHeight,
                  alignItems: "center",
                }
              : {
                  alignItems: "center",
                }
          }
          value={username}
          onLayout={(event) => {
            dimensions(event.nativeEvent.layout, 0);
          }}
          onFocus={() => {
            setIsOnFocus(1);
            console.warn(window.height);
          }}
          onBlur={() => {
            setIsOnFocus(0);
          }}
        />
        <CustomInput
          ref={textInputs[1]}
          onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "Email")}
          placeholder="Email"
          style={
            isOnFocus == 2
              ? {
                  position: "absolute",
                  width: "100%",
                  bottom: keyboardHeight,
                  alignItems: "center",
                }
              : {
                  alignItems: "center",
                }
          }
          value={email}
          onLayout={(event) => {
            dimensions(event.nativeEvent.layout, 1);
          }}
          onFocus={() => {
            setIsOnFocus(2);
          }}
          onBlur={() => {
            setIsOnFocus(0);
          }}
        />
      </View>

      <CustomButton
        text="Suivant"
        onPress={onRegisterPressed}
        type="PRIMARY"
        top="-1%"
      />

      <SocialSignInButtons />

      <CustomButton
        text="Have an account? Sign In"
        onPress={onSignInPressed}
        type="TERTIARY"
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

// (rnss)
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.background_Pale,
    flex: 1,
    //justifyContent: "center",
    //alignItems: "center",
  },
  imageBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    // height: null,
    // width: null,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  link: { color: "#FDB075" },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.background_Pale,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "gray",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#360d59",
    margin: 10,
    top: "34.5%",
    right: "25%",
  },
});

export default SignUpScreen;
```

Here's my CustomInput component:

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from "react";
import { COLORS } from "../../assets/Colors/Colors";

const CustomInput = forwardRef(
  (
    { onFocus = () => {}, onBlur = () => {}, onLayout, label, style, ...props },
    ref
  ) => {
    const [isOnFocus, setIsOnFocus] = useState(false);

    return (
      <View style={[{ width: "100%" }, style]}>
        {label && <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{label}</Text>}
        <View
          style={[
            styles.container,
            { borderColor: isOnFocus ? "yellow" : COLORS.input_Border_Violet },
          ]}
        >
          <TextInput
            ref={ref}
            autocorrect={false}
            style={styles.input}
            {...props}
            onFocus={() => {
              onFocus();
              setIsOnFocus(true);
            }}
            onLayout={onLayout}
            onBlur={() => {
              onBlur();
              setIsOnFocus(false);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "80%",

    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 2,

    marginVertical: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  input: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
  subtitle: {
    color: COLORS.background,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});

export default CustomInput;
```

For some reason, the CustomInput isn't raised over the keyboard, it's either in part or fully covered by the keyboard depending on the device. I am not getting in errors and e.endCoordinates.height is returning a value, just not the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

This is how I made it work:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  ImageBackground,
  Keyboard,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from "react-native";

import Constants from "expo-constants";

import { COLORS } from "../../assets/Colors/Colors";

import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton";
import CustomInput from "../../components/CustomInput";
import SocialSignInButtons from "../../components/SocialSignInButtons";

const SignUpScreen = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);
  const [isOnFocus, setIsOnFocus] = useState(0);

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const window = useWindowDimensions();
  const textInput1 = useRef();
  const textInput2 = useRef();
  const textInputs = [textInput1, textInput2];

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      textInputs[0].current?.focus();
    }, 0);
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      (e) => {
        setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
      }
    );

    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener();

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const onRegisterPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignUp2");
  };

  const onSignInPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignIn");
  };

  const onTermsOfUsePressed = () => {
    console.warn("Terms of Use");
  };
  const onPrivacyPolicyPressed = () => {
    console.warn("Privacy Policy");
  };

  const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    eval(`set${type}`)(e);
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      resizeMode="stretch"
      source={require("../../assets/AppCustomBackgroundsFrench/SignUpFR.png")}
      style={styles.imageBackground}
    >
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.title, { top: window.height * 0.34 }]}>
          S'inscrire
        </Text>
        <View
          style={
            isOnFocus != 0 && keyboardHeight != 0
              ? {
                  position: "absolute",
                  width: "100%",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  bottom: keyboardHeight,
                }
              : {
                  position: "absolute",
                  width: "100%",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  top: window.height * 0.37 + 49,
                }
          }
        >
          <CustomInput
            ref={textInputs[0]}
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "Username")}
            placeholder="Username"
            style={{
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            value={username}
            onFocus={() => {
              setIsOnFocus(1);
              console.warn(window.height);
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              setIsOnFocus(0);
            }}
          />
          <CustomInput
            ref={textInputs[1]}
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "Email")}
            placeholder="Email"
            style={{
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            value={email}
            onFocus={() => {
              setIsOnFocus(1);
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              setIsOnFocus(0);
            }}
          />
        </View>

        <CustomButton
          text="Suivant"
          onPress={onRegisterPressed}
          type="PRIMARY"
          top="-1%"
        />

        <SocialSignInButtons />

        <CustomButton
          text="Have an account? Sign In"
          onPress={onSignInPressed}
          type="TERTIARY"
        />
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

// (rnss)
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.background_Pale,
    flex: 1,
    //justifyContent: "center",
    //alignItems: "center",
  },
  imageBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    // height: null,
    // width: null,
    //alignItems: "center",
  },
  link: { color: "#FDB075" },
  text: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "gray",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  title: {
    position: "absolute",
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#360d59",
    margin: 10,
    left: "9.7%",
  },
});

export default SignUpScreen;
```